# Data Limit on MySQL DB Insert

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I was wondering if there was a limit to the size of data to be Inserted into a MySQL database?

I seem to be successfully Inserting records but when certain textarea fields get large, it seems like the records won't Insert.  Can someone let me know if there is a size limit or if there is just an error?

Thanks.

Brett

Comment: There is the [max_allow_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) setting which governs the client<->server connection.

Comment: I use to change the value of max_allowed_packet to 32M. You can do it in the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends in the disk and memory size and network limitations mostly:

Quote From my sql website:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

> The maximum size of a BLOB or TEXT object is determined by its type,
>   but the largest value you actually can transmit between the client and
>   server is determined by the amount of available memory and the size of
>   the communications buffers. You can change the message buffer size by
>   changing the value of the max_allowed_packet variable, but you must do
>   so for both the server and your client program