# MySQL insert query failing when data gets large

Tags: php, mysql

I have already followed the question:[Data Limit on MySQL DB Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651854/data-limit-on-mysql-db-insert) I was unable to solve it with the limited info.
I am using WAMP.
I have numerous Rich Text editors and 4 images which are being sent over to another page by a POST request. After a certain threshold limit, the query is failing. Is there a way around?

EDIT: while displaying the query string it seems that I am able to retrieve every bit of data that was sent via POST. I am quite sure that it is DB related. 
Images are being stored as a BLOB.

EDIT #2: Error showing is "MySQL server has gone away".

Comment: Aman, I think we'll need more info here in terms of DDL for the table, config on the source/client and the mysql database, and an example (ideally reproducible) of your sql.  I'm not a DBA but usually with those bits of info the question is a lot easier to answer.

Comment: what is in logs? are you sure its db issue, maybe you reached post_max_size or upload_max_filesize?

Comment: can you post your query..? So we can answer you more precisely..

Comment: I have updated the statement. Please let me know if I can be more descriptive. The query result which I am storing in $result is setting to NULL. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be violating the `max_allowed_packet` setting. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/packet-too-large.html) for more data.

Quote,

> If you are using the mysql client program, its default
>   max_allowed_packet variable is 16MB.

If you are uploading uncompressed images, this value is fairly easy to reach.

Also, it would be great if you could name the specific database interface class that you use (PDO? mysql_? mysqli_?), as different classes handle errors differently. It could just as well not handle an oversized packet situation at all.

P.S.: You should really be checking your logs for the specific error you encounter. The first place to look for would be `/var/log/mysql/error.log` (could vary depending on your env)

**Update:**
`mysql_error()` returned `"MySQL server has gone away"`

> From the manual pages for the error: "You can also get these errors if
>   you send a query to the server that is incorrect or too large. If
>   mysqld receives a packet that is too large or out of order, it assumes
>   that something has gone wrong with the client and closes the
>   connection. If you need big queries (for example, if you are working
>   with big BLOB columns), you can increase the query limit by setting
>   the server's max_allowed_packet variable, which has a default value of
>   1MB. You may also need to increase the maximum packet size on the
>   client end..."

(quote courtesy of @Colin Morelli)

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin and images that I am uploading as BLOB are in KB's(not more than 50). In mysql.log I am not getting anthing related to this and I am not able to find error.log anywhere in mysql.

Comment: @AmanChhabra, Try eyeballing your /var/log folder for mysql* files or directories in case you missed something. Also try checking your webserver log files for errors.

Another point: are you certain the query correctly reaches your database? Could there be a data transition problem before your mysql call?

Comment: I have changed every field to longtext and longblob. Also $result=mysql_query($sql) is returning null and there are no log entries. I am a noob sorry if I didnt get what you meant. Also I even searched for every log files... there is no path as you mentioned.

Comment: @AmanChhabra Are you aware that the `mysql_*` class is deprecated and no longer fully supported? Regardless, try running `mysql_error()` to see why your request failed.

Comment: I will change that... the error displaying is "MySQL server has gone away".

Comment: From the manual pages for the error: "You can also get these errors if you send a query to the server that is incorrect or too large. If mysqld receives a packet that is too large or out of order, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. If you need big queries (for example, if you are working with big BLOB columns), you can increase the query limit by setting the server's max_allowed_packet variable, which has a default value of 1MB. You may also need to increase the maximum packet size on the client end..."

Answer (score 0):

sometimes, php tends to reach the memory limit if the file uploaded is too large. depending on your config, this might help:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Comment: I tried it and it has not helped. I have updated the statement, please go through it. Thank you.

Comment: I am using wamp and I cant find error.log only thing related is mysql.log which do not contain anything related to this. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
if it is not the memory allocation thing we all rushed to answer 
then it could be a memory engine tidbit so you could probably check that,

comment:
in my experience, it is most likely a memory issue, since it only occurs when you try bigger imports
(happens to my application when i try to return a 20MB result set from a single query)

Comment: I have already used ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); Should I try something else too if it is a memory bug?

Comment: i see above, that you use mysql_query, not related to your problem i think but you should use the mysqli instead since mysql is depreciated